# How to assign the source of an image in a style wrapping ListBoxItem

Tags: wpf, image, listbox, listboxitem

In the following code, there is a style for ListBoxItem, with a textblock and an Image. 
The textblock has a binding to the ListBoxItem content, and the Image is set in the style.
I want to be able to set this image for each listboxitem and in code, I'm wondering if 
someone can get me on the right track.

Thanks for any help.

code snippet of the style and using it:

```
<Style x:Key="ExpanderListitemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image x:Name="iGalleryPreview" Source="images/someImage.png" Width="18" Height="18"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="con" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Margin="5,0,0,0">
    <TextBlock.Foreground>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF2A485C" x:Name="contentColor" />
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>

<ListBox BorderThickness="0" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ExpanderListitemStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">
    <ListBoxItem Content="Some Label"  />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Another Label"/>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume we have an `Employee` class, we store for each employee her name and image as follows:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of a `Style` you need to use an `ItemTemplate` as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="ProofOfConcept.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                     <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground"
                                    Value="Green"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground"
                                    Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="24"
                                   Width="24" Margin="2,1"
                                   Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

your code behind will be something like this:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace ProofOfConcept
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var emps =
                new Employee[]
                    {
                        new Employee {Image = "/Images/1.png", Name = "Mohamed A. Fadil"},
                        new Employee {Image = "/Images/6.png", Name = "Sara Konor :)"},
                        new Employee {Image = "/Images/2.png", Name = "John M. Arther"},
                        new Employee {Image = "/Images/3.png", Name = "Khalid El-Sheikh"},
                        new Employee {Image = "/Images/4.png", Name = "Hassan A. Fadil"},
                        new Employee {Image = "/Images/5.png", Name = "Criss Redfield"}
                    };
            DataContext = emps;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the result :D

[image: THe Final Result]

Comment: My style controltemplate does a lot to change colors, like mouse over color, selected color, animation with mouse over the item, etc.. Would this still be possible using a itemtemplate? Sorry, pretty new to wpf.

Comment: @Mottai, No problem you can set both of them, see the updated XAML code

Comment: Thanks. How would you change the background when selected. I tried in your example where you changed the foreground, that worked, but if i changed it to the background i just got the default selected color of a listboxitem. I also tried setting the listboxitem background to transparent, then wrapped a border around the controls and set it's background, the default selected color still came through. Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Hi. In reference to my last comment. I found an example at this site. 
<Style.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                             Color="Black"/>
                        </Style.Resources>